# Select2 iOS Browser scrolling issue

Tags: jquery-mobile, mobile-safari, jquery-select2

I'm using [Select2](https://select2.github.io/) as dropdown with jQuery Mobile. Scrolling through the list works good on an Android browser. The list flows freely. But on On iOS devices, the scrolling isn't flowing freely. The scrolling halts immediately. Refer to [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9vJDmfd2qb9MmdMd1BEaDhMdnc/view?usp=sharing).

Help is required in fixing this.

Comment: try adding `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` to containing div.

Comment: Works fine. You may add this as the answer

Comment: You can take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48313498/select2-produces-rough-scrolling-on-mobile/49560827#49560827 for a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; to containing div.

Answered by: [Omar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1771795/omar)