# Select2 produces rough scrolling on mobile

Tags: jquery-select2

I'm testing the Select2 jQuery component on an iPhone, and all I did was open their demo website:

https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage

If you test their State example on a phone, scrolling doesn't respond to pressure and doesn't fade smoothly. It's a rough line scroll. When you move your thumb, the lines don't fade in and out.

On the other hand, on a desktop the scrolling/fading works great. It responds gracefully to mouse-wheel scrolls.

Just wondering has anyone noticed this?

EDIT Looks like iOS (unlike Android) requires

```
<div style="-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;">
```

for smooth scrolling of DIVs: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Jun/01/Smoothing-out-div-scrolling-in-Mobile-WebKit-Browsers

Comment: I tested on Android 7.0 and it works well

Comment: @beaver Looks like Androids enable webkit touch by default so you don't get that: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Jun/01/Smoothing-out-div-scrolling-in-Mobile-WebKit-Browsers . But in iOS we're missing `<div style="-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading your answer, it is not very clear how to add the `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` property to the `select2` element, so I've decided to give a more detailed answer:

#### Details:

According to specs (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-overflow-scrolling), the `-webkit-overflow-scrolling` CSS property controls whether or not touch devices use momentum-based scrolling for a given element.

A `touch` value means that the content continues to scroll for a while after finishing the scroll gesture and removing your finger from the touchscreen.

**However, this property applies only for iOS devices. Android works well even without it.**

#### Usage:

We must append this property to the dropdown element that holds the suggestions - `.select2-results__options`.

Add the following code after the `select2` css styles:

```
.select2-results__options {
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

#### Demo:

https://codepen.io/andreivictor/pen/NYvvXP

(the following demo contains two select2 instances for a better comparison of the scroll effects)

#### Tested on:

- iPhone 6 Plus (iOS 10.3.2)
- iPhone 8 (iOS 11.2.5)
- iPad Mini 3 (iOS 10.3.2)

Comment: Yes. That's what I had to do. The rough scrolling was only on iPhones, and the -webkit-overflow-scrolling fixed it. Surprised it wasn't a widely reported problem with Select2.

Comment: Indeed, I was surprised too. There is no open issue about this on github or on select2 forums(https://forums.select2.org/). This is probably because we don't test enough our responsive interfaces directly on mobile devices and we're happy with our desktop browser's responsive features.